# Whitelabel Error Page While doing Web Scraping with jsoup in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, jsoup

i am new to spring, i just created a simple web **scraping** spring boot project, getting some path variable and call JSOUP to get document and than **scrape** some kind of stuff from document.The problem i am facing is it works perfectly fine in my local host, i deployed to heroku server and inside real server its not working, i think network call could not be made or something else.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
@RequestMapping("/grabMedia/{postID}")
public MyModel Grab(@PathVariable String postID) {
    String POSTURL = buildPostUrl(postID);
    try {
        return parseGrabModel(POSTURL);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new InstaGrab(null, "Error : " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), true);
    }
}

private MyModel parseGrabModel(String url) throws IOException {
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0").get();
    MyModel grabModel = new MyModel();
    grabModel.setGrabbedMedia(mediaList(document.toString()));
    grabModel.setMessage("Success");
    return grabModel;
}


private List<Media> mediaList(String content) {
    ** did some scraping here **
    ** while loop etc **
    ** and returns the list **
    return mediaList;
 }
}
```

is there i am doing any mistake or some other server config should i have to do. its working perfectly fine in local server but after deployed not works

> Whitelabel Error Page
> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).

white label error page arrives ...

Comment: Hi - I think the terms you want are ‘scrape’ and ‘scraping’, because ‘scrap’ and ‘scrapping’ are about throwing things aeay.

Comment: oh sorry my bad :/ but as you understand .... i mean web scraping 'scrape' .... ;P

Comment: can you understand whats wrong or mistake i made ?

Comment: are you getting any errors at your spring boot side?

Comment: no not getting any error... works 100% perfectly fine in my localhost ... i call endpoint and the scrapping works fine no any issue ....